# The minimal degree of Affine group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

My question is about the problem 3.3.3 of the book "Permutation Groups" by Dixon and Mortimer.

Let a group $G$ acting on a set $X$ has nontrivial elements with finite support, where for $x\in G$ $supp(x)=\{ \alpha \in X:\alpha^x\ne \alpha \}$. We define the **minimal degree** of $G$ to be the minimum of $\vert supp(x)\vert$ for all $1\ne x\in G$.

Let $F=F_q$ be the finite field with $q$ elements and $d\ge 1$. For each linear transformation $a \in GL_d(F)$ and vector $v\in F^d$, we define the affine transformation $t_{a,v}:F^d\rightarrow F^d$ by $t_{a,v}:u\mapsto ua+v$.
Let $AGL_d(F)=\{t_{a,v}: a \in GL_d(F),v\in F^d\}$, the affine group of dimension $d$ over $F$. Suppose that $AGL_d(F)$ act on $F^d$. obviously, the degree of this action is $q^d$.

I want to prove that the minimal degree of $AGL_d(F)$ is $q^{d-1}(q-1)$. For solving this problem let $\alpha \ne 0,1$ and $W=(\alpha-1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ and $A$ be the matrix \begin{bmatrix}\alpha^{-1} & 0\\0 & I_{d-1}\end{bmatrix}
So, $t_{A,W}\in AGL_d(F)$ and $\vert supp(x)\vert=q^{d-1}(q-1)$ since $supp(t_{A,W})=\{(\alpha,a_1,\ldots,a_{d-1})\in F^d\}$. Now, I want to prove that this element has the minimal size of $supp(x)$ between all $1\ne x\in AGL_d(F)$, but I don't know how. Also, I don't know that this element lead me to the best solution or not.

I will be so grateful for your helpful hints, comments and answers.

Comment: Nice hat.  12345

Comment: You are looking for a nontrivial element $t_{a,v}$ that fixes a maximal number of points.  Since $G$ acts transitively on $X$, we can assume that $t_{a,v}$ fixes $0$ or, equivalently, that $v=0$. But now $t_{a,0}$ is an element of ${\rm GL}_d(F)$ and its fixed point set is a proper subspace of $F^d$. The maximal number of points in such a subspace is $q^{d-1}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thank you so much because of your helpful comment. I understand that finding an element $a$ in $GL_d(F)$ with $\vert Fix(a)\vert =q^{d-1}$ is sufficient. Also, $Fix(a)$ is a subspace of $F^d$. But I don't understand why there is an element in $GL_d(F)$ which **is not identity** and fixes **each vector** in a subspace of $F^d$ with dimension $d-1$!

Comment: Just take a diagonal matrix in which $d-1$ of the entries on the diagonal are equal to $1$. You have  done that yourself in the question!

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thank you so much. I thought it is something different :)